# Vlookup #N/A error but value exist in table array

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an Excel file that I'm trying to get help on why my vlookup formula is creating #N/A so how do I attach an excel file for posting on this forum?

I have a table that I'm trying to get the ItemLookup column to correspond to the ID column but I'm getting #N/A errors for quite a few of them.  I would attach the file but I don't see an option on how to do this in the forum.

Comment: Firstly change the tittle of your question describing your real issue of `vlookup`. Then you can upload the file online and can share the link.

Comment: How do you change the tite of the question, Mrig?

Comment: Ok go it changed.  How do you attach an excel file?

Comment: No option to attach excel file here, you can add it to your dropbox or drive and share the link

Comment: Upload the file on any of the online file sharing site and mention that link in question.

Comment: Or else you can show sample of data in your file as text in the question along with a screenshot attached as an image.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up looking online and found that my data in each column needed to be the same.  Once I did  Data > Text to Columns > Finish and had the data formatted as the same type the vlookup worked.